# Regarding SEO, is repeating some content in different pages considered as keyword stuffing?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, keywords, keyword-stuffing

We know that repeating keywords in one page is spam and Google calls it keyword stuffing.

But, if we repeat some content in all pages of a website to help users, is it keyword stuffing too?

For example we have 200 unique words in each page and about 200 other words to describe how to download and how to buy and what other services you may get from this website and etc.

Or if we repeat some keyword in `<title>` of all pages like this:

- `Download PDF: Article one`
- `Download PDF: Article two`
- `Download PDF: Article three`
- etc.

Is repeating **`Download PDF : Article`** in titles, spam or keyword stuffing? If not, is it a positive point to get more visitor from Google?

Answer (score 4):

If your repeated content is used to help your users and doesn't content keywords of your website, I don't think it would be considered as keyword stuffing by search engines.

However, if you want to avoid potential duplicate content issues, you can avoid repeating this paragraph over your all pages and migrate it to a new page like an "help center to download a PDF". Then, you put a link to this new page on all your pages.

Otherwise, for repeating keywords in `<title>` tags, you can do it if it's relevant in relation to your page. I think that Google can understand your pages are created automatically by a script. And don't forget all your `<title>` tags are unique.

Answer (score 4):

The only consideration I see is that the words *download, PDF, and article* will become likely the top three or at least within the top ten keywords your *site* is known for therefore the site topic as seen by Google and/or Bing maybe that of *article download*. There may be two problems with that:

1. Your site is not about article downloading. It can dilute the SEO effect of the other keywords your site is known for and the performance of any page on a page by page basis depending and performance overall.
2. Article sharing sites have been hit hard lately and algorithms exist to identify these sites. There may be a chance that your site will fall into this category. It may be a small chance, but *in* is in.

Pay attention to the Content Keywords in Google Webmaster Tools. It is critically important that these keywords reflect your site topic before SEO begins. It is the foundation upon which the rest of your work will rest upon.

If you find this is the case, perhaps you can have your cake and eat it too. Only in web design does this work. You can change your links to the PDFs from a text link to an image link and if you repeat the article title in the alt text, then you should be more than okay. In this case, it may be okay to use the terms *download, PDF, and article* too. Just make sure you are mixing up the alt text with the article title.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't know that _Article sharing sites have been hit hard lately and algorithms exist to identify these sites_. May you give me a reference about it ? when did Google hit them ? What is the exact definition of an "Article sharing site" ?

Comment: http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2271305/Google-Penguin-2.0-Casualties-Why-Sites-Got-Hit does get into details or offer a list. http://pandalized.com/ shows some sites but does not cover all sites. The Washington Post was hit for example mostly for linking schemes. http://greekgeek.squidoo.com/how-googles-panda-update-impacted-squidoo-and-hubpages-traffic talks about squidoo and hubpages. Many sites like these were hit. Your own article site is not the issue except that is has effected personal blogs too. Mostly just article sharing sites that were designed to game the system.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I didn't get the answer of my question yet ! is repeating some content in different pages considered as keyword stuffing?

Comment: Not as you described. However, my answer is still a real concern. Repeating keywords is not generally advised except where prescribed in links, titles, descriptions, header tags, and so forth. As you described it, you would not penalize, but it will dilute your performance by increasing the importance of words that may not help your search results.